# This django app asks a mutiple-choice question from the user

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

The app checks the user answer and shows the result and then checks if the user answered the question or not. if the user answered the question the options will **disable** and **checks **the option that user **selected**

but i got that error:
TemplateSyntaxError at /questions/

Could not parse the remainder: '[question.id]' from 'answers[question.id]'

html:

```
`
{% for question in questions %}
<div class="question">
    <p>{{ question.text }}</p>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'submit_answer' question.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="question" value="{{ question.id }}">
    <input type="radio" id="option_1_{{ question.id }}" name="answer" value="1" {% if 1 in answers[{{question.id}}] %}checked{% endif %} {% if answers[question.id] is not None %}disabled{% endif %}>
    <label for="option_1_{{ question.id }}">{{ question.option_1 }}</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="option_1_{{ question.id }}" name="answer" value="2" {% if 2 in answers[question.id] %}checked{% endif %} {% if answers[question.id] is not None %}disabled{% endif %}>  
    <label for="option_2_{{ question.id }}">{{ question.option_2 }}</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="option_1_{{ question.id }}" name="answer" value="3" {% if 3 in     answers[question.id] %}checked{% endif %} {% if answers[question.id] is not None %}disabled{% endif %}>
    <label for="option_3_{{ question.id }}">{{ question.option_3 }}</label>
    <br>
    {% if not request.session.question_answers.get(str(question.id)) %}
    <button type="submit">Submit Answer</button>
    {% else %}
    <p>Your answer has been submitted.</p>
    {% endif %}
    </form>
</div>
{% endfor %}
`
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Question

def questions(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    answers = {}

    # Check if the user has already answered each question
    for question in questions:
        answer_key = 'answer_' + str(question.id)
        if answer_key in request.session:
            answers[question.id] = request.session[answer_key]

    context = {
        'questions': questions,
        'answers': answers
    }
    return render(request, 'questions.html', context)

def submit_answers(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        question_id = request.POST.get('question')
        answer_text = request.POST.get('answer')
        question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)

        # Save the answer to the session
        request.session['answer_' + str(question_id)] = answer_text

        # Provide feedback to the user
        if answer_text == question.correct_answer:
            messages.success(request, 'Your answer is correct!')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Your answer is incorrect.')

    return redirect('questions')
```